# Loop with two arguments file bash script

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

Writing simple script where I need to take arguments IP and name from file.

list.txt:

```
0.0.0.0 a
0.0.0.1 a1
...
```

Script example:

```
list=$(cat list.txt)
for ip, name in list
do
    ssh $ip 
    virsh reset $name
done
```

What I need is correct syntax firstly to iterate through *ip* and then in same loop reset by *name*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `read` here to read `ip` and `name` in 2 different varibles:

```
while read -r ip name; do
    ssh "$ip"
    virsh reset "$name"
done < list.txt
```